# Instagram hook com.instagram.exclusivegram not so exclusive

Tags: ios, api, hook, instagram

As far as I know, you have to use **com.instagram.photo** to get the general options and **com.instagram.exclusivegram** for the documentinteractioncontroller's UTI if you really only want Instagram + use the correct extension **.ig** for general and **.igo** for exclusive Instagram.

For some reason, I see multiple options and not just Instagram like I want to..

Did I forgot something? Is it done differently?

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    CGRect cropRect=CGRectMake(0,0,612,612);
    // ig voor gewone instagram, igo voor exclusive instagram
    NSString *jpgPath=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/temp/photo.igo"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath]];
    // exclusive zou direct in de instagram app moeten openen, helaas toont hij meerdere opties met instagram ergenes helemaal achteraan
    self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.documentInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
    self.documentInteractionController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Alweer een Nostalgie deelnemer! #nostalgiebusje" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect inView: self.view animated: YES ];
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please, post your `setupControllerWithURL:usingDelegate:` method. Result of this method is assigned to `documentInteractionController` property after you set `UTI` string.

Answer (score 6):

Using the file extension `igo` is correct, and the number of apps that will appear in the list is considerably less than if you used `ig`. From my testing (iOS 9 only), the UTI made no difference to the presented list.

Looks like the [iPhone hooks doc](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) is outdated.

Answer (score 5):

```
self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
self.documentInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
```

It seems that UTI string is overwritten by `setupControllerWithURL:usingDelegate:` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a temporary copy of the image with a "ig" or "igo" extension, then share that with UTI "com.instagram.exclusivegram".  This should present the DocumentInteractionController with only the Instagram option:

```
if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:tempDirectory])
[fm createDirectoryAtPath:tempDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *tempInstagramPath = [tempDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instagramShare.igo"];
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:tempInstagramPath])
    [fm removeItemAtPath:tempInstagramPath error:nil];

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToShare, 1.0) writeToFile:tempInstagramPath atomically:NO];

documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempInstagramPath]];
documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
documentInteractionController.annotation = @{@"InstagramCaption": @"My Photo Caption!"};
if (![documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated:YES])
    NSLog(@"Cannot open Document Interaction Controller for sharing with Instagram");
```